# PostUrlEncodedAsync with complex object

Tags: flurl

Hi I'm trying to post an object that is like :

```
    public class myobj
{
public string name {get;set;}
public myEntity myentity {get;set;}
public mySecondEntity mySecondEntity {get;set;}

}

public class myEntity {get;set;}
{
public string name {get;set;}
public string description {get;set;}
}

public class mySecondEntity {get;set;}
{
public string name {get;set;}
public string description {get;set;}
}
```

When I use generate a new object of myObj and use PostUrlEncodedAsync it is posting it as :

```
 name : "myname",
 myentity : "detex.Models.DTO.myEntity",
 mysecondentity : "detex.Models.DTO.mySecondEntity
```

Not sure what my namespace/class is doing in those fields.  I'm posting this as 
await "myurl.com".PostUrlEncodedAsync(_model).

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

Flurl assumes that objects passed to `PostUrlEncodedAsync` represent simple name/value pairs. It simply does a `ToString` on your values, which is why you're getting `detex.Models.DTO.myEntity`. Do you want those values serialized to JSON? If so you'll need to do that yourself:

```
"myurl.com".PostUrlEncodedAsync(new {
    name = _model.name,
    myentity = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_model.myentity),
    mysecondentity = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_model.mySecondEntity)
});
```

Posting complex objects as URL-encoded is not typical, which is why serializing those values is not built into Flurl.

Comment: Thanks Todd, do you know of a way that to convert complex object into a name value pair ?

Comment: How do you want to serialize the values? There is no standard. My answer shows how to serialize them as JSON. Not what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Todd, I already attempted to serialize the entire object - differently to your method and I believe I received a BadRequest from the endpoint.

Comment: Are you certain you want PostUrlEncodedAsync and not PostJsonAsync?